# Why does the Ajax post update script not work?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I wrote a small script for editing the post, in principle, everything works, except for updating the picture and I don’t understand what is the reason. Without Ajax, everything works as it should. I tried to see what formData will show me through console.log and alert, it shows all the data except the image

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        $("#editPostButton{{$post->id}}").click(function() {

            var formData = $("#EditPostForm{{$post->id}}").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('editPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html($(data).find("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html());
                    $("#closeButton{{$post->id}}").click();
                }
           });

        });
    });
```

Form itself

```
<form action="{{route('editPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="EditPostForm{{$post->id}}" name="postForm">
@csrf @method('PATCH')
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea maxlength="100" name="title" class="form-control" rows="1">{{$post->title}}</textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="message" maxlength="5000" name="message" class="form-control" rows="10">{{$post->message}}</textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea maxlength="100" class="form-control mt-1" id="videoPost" name="videoPost" cols="100" rows="1">{{$post->videoPost}}</textarea>
</div>
<h6>Current image</h6>
<img src="{{$post->img}}" class="img-fluid mb-2" width="230">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="editPostButton{{$post->id}}">Edit</button>
```

Comment: You need to pass csrf from ajax

Comment: csrf is in the form as a directive.  Probably fine, I haven't tried, I always do header too.  Anyway, my 2 cents are to look at the OPTIONS route.  Please provide the http error response in your question so we can see more about the issue.  Depending how this is hosted, it could be CORS or OPTIONS or both.

Comment: Text data through Ajax is updated, but the image is not updated in any way. I just can't get the picture

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass CSRF from ajax :

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        $("#editPostButton{{$post->id}}").click(function() {

            var formData = $("#EditPostForm{{$post->id}}").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 },
                url: "{{route('editPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html($(data).find("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html());
                    $("#closeButton{{$post->id}}").click();
                }
           });

        });
    });
```

Comment: I am fine with the token. I just can't get the picture

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup Ajax CSRF like:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```